# Equivalent function for select system call in linux kernel space in c?

Tags: linux, select, kernel, system-calls

I would like to implement linux client socket program in kernel space. I was not able to  remove my module when my control is in kernel_recvmsg since it is blocking call.

So I decided to use select to read the data to avoid blocking issue.I know select works only for user space.Can you please tell me the system call for select in kernel space.

Comment: Some helpful links :

http://codereply.com/answer/5obbiw/simulate-effect-select-poll-kernel-socket-programming.html

http://codereply.com/answer/8kj7n4/using-selectpoll-device-driver.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link you have given but the above link gives details on simulation of select call. Sock_create in kernel space is similar to socket in user space. Similar to that may I know the kernel function for select call which is used in user space.